# How to design workflow

Tags: performance, rest, jmeter-5.0

I need to create a workflow where a user would send emails to either 1 or multiple depending on how many they are available on the account from the dropdown recipients.

I started creating a workflow but got stuck can a thread group contain sub-thread group at one of the endpoints? If so how? Need some example.

**Requirement**: The design should accept a single user / multiple users and each of the users can send emails to single recipients or multiple recipients